# How to control the number of rows in a JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

How do I set the number of rows to be displayed per page in a report using iReports.
Ex: if i have 100 records, I wasnt to display 10 per page and then break. The default behavior is to cram all the records possible in the page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok! Found a way to accomplish this!

1. The rows are usually printed in the `Details` band.
2. At the end of the details band, where you need a page break, add a pagebreak.
3. In the pageBreak's properties, edit the printWhen Expression from the properties pane.
4. The expression will be

`new java.lang.Boolean((int)($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue())%10==0)`

where 10 is the number of records per page.

This is how it is done in iReports. The jrxml equivalent for people directly editing the file is as below.

```
<break>
    <reportElement x="0" y="23" width="100" height="1">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.Boolean((int)($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue())%10==0)]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
</break>
```

Put this just after the `<band>` tag under `<details>` tag.

Comment: This solution works well if the page has more than 10 rows (like in the sample from the answer). In case if the number of rows is less than specified number (the textField's height can grow) , the design will be broken. Another problem - the situation when we have a report with an even number of pages 10, for example 40. The empty page will be added at the end of report.

Comment: @AlexK I don't have access to Jasper at the moment, so cannot confirm, but when the records are less than 10, the page break simply does not get added. So for records less than 10, there won't be a page break and everything gets printed in the first page. The next part about adding an extra page might be true, can't remember what workaround I used.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the page height you set.

Comment: Page height is not the right way to comtrol, if the text size changes, the count goes for a toss. Isn't there any other way to specify the count?

Comment: Then you can do that using Variables. You can get increment a variable till your desired limit reaches. After that you have to start in an other page. I don't know if there is another way to do this.

Comment: Found a way, see my answer to the post.

Comment: I adjust my page hight and everything came correctly, FYI my all fonts was constants at 11.