# How do I limit the number of rows on each page?

Tags: jasper-reports

I would like to be able to control the max number of rows in each page to 5. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: you really need to elaborate more. A better description of EXACTLY what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: i have one table .i want to set numbering 1-5 for each page because i have 100 data for table. every page i have a 5 row of data. For example,i want for page one have 1-5,page two 1-5 and so on until the end

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control the number of rows in a JasperReport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059536/how-to-control-the-number-of-rows-in-a-jasperreport)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need add a "Break" element to your Detail band with a Print When Expression similar to this:

```
$V{REPORT_COUNT} % 5 == 0
```

Comment: thank you but how to set numbering 1-5 for each page because i have 100 data for table. every page i have a 5 row of data. i want for page one have 1-5,page two 1-5 and so on until the end.

Comment: Above is for limit but i want to display blank rows also.If y page have to display 10 rows and only 5 data come then also display 5 rows as a blank .how can i achieve ?