# how to display data less than 5 row in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a report table. I have set it to display 5 rows of data per page. The problem now is when there are less than 5 rows of data the table will not appear.

I have put `$V{REPORT_COUNT} %5 == 0` in every section.

How can I modify this formula so that the data rows will display even though there are less than 5 rows?

Comment: Did you try to use the `page break` element?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I limit the number of rows on each page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617082/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-on-each-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry that I couldn't reply earlier, as I'd a busy day at work. After looking at your report design, I found that 'Page Break' functionality is not something that you really need. I just changed the Group Expression for the group that you have, to : **$F{PARENT_NAME} + 
(($V{REPORT_COUNT} % 5 == 0) ? "1" : "2")** and set the 'Start on new page' parameter to true. Also, I changed the Chart data. Check the below jrxml data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ChartLineBless" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="P_YEAR" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="P_AGENCY_CODE" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="P_SECTOR_LOOK_CODE" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <field name="PARENT_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PARENT_NAME_SECTOR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AGENCY_PARENT_CODE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AGENCY_CODE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AGENCY_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="YEAR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SECTOR_ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SECTOR_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="DYEAR1" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="DYEAR2" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="DYEAR3" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="DYEAR4" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="DYEAR5" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="YR1" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="YR2" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="YR3" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="YR4" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="YR5" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <variable name="YR1_1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="agensi" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR1}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="YR2_1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="agensi" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR2}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="YR3_1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="agensi" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR3}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="YR4_1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="agensi" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR4}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="YR5_1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="agensi" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR5}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="agensi" isStartNewPage="true" minHeightToStartNewPage="550">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{PARENT_NAME} + 
(($V{REPORT_COUNT} % 5 == 0) ? "1" : "2")]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="98">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="332" y="84" width="85" height="14"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="247" y="84" width="85" height="14"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="43" y="71" width="204" height="27"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Agency Name]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="10" y="71" width="33" height="27"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[No.]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="417" y="84" width="85" height="14"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR3}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="247" y="71" width="425" height="13"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Year]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="672" y="71" width="85" height="27"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Total]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="587" y="84" width="85" height="14"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR5}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="502" y="84" width="85" height="14"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR4}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="22" width="802" height="26"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[5 YEAR STATISTICS ON APPLICATION RECEIVED (BY ALL AGENCIES)]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="208">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} % 5 == 0]]></printWhenExpression>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="672" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new Integer($V{YR1_1}.intValue() + $V{YR2_1}.intValue()+
$V{YR3_1}.intValue()+ $V{YR4_1}.intValue())+ $V{YR5_1}.intValue()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="237" height="20"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[                                                                   Total]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="587" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{YR5_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="502" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{YR4_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="417" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{YR3_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="332" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{YR2_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="247" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{YR1_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <lineChart>
                    <chart>
                        <reportElement x="144" y="34" width="549" height="173"/>
                        <chartTitle/>
                        <chartSubtitle/>
                        <chartLegend/>
                    </chart>
                    <categoryDataset>
                        <dataset resetType="Page"/>
                        <categorySeries>
                            <seriesExpression><![CDATA["YEAR1"]]></seriesExpression>
                            <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR1}]]></categoryExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$V{YR1_1}]]></valueExpression>
                        </categorySeries>
                        <categorySeries>
                            <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Year2"]]></seriesExpression>
                            <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR2}]]></categoryExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$V{YR2_1}]]></valueExpression>
                        </categorySeries>
                        <categorySeries>
                            <seriesExpression><![CDATA["YEAR3"]]></seriesExpression>
                            <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR3}]]></categoryExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$V{YR3_1}]]></valueExpression>
                        </categorySeries>
                        <categorySeries>
                            <seriesExpression><![CDATA["YEAR4"]]></seriesExpression>
                            <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR4}]]></categoryExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$V{YR4_1}]]></valueExpression>
                        </categorySeries>
                        <categorySeries>
                            <seriesExpression><![CDATA["YEAR5"]]></seriesExpression>
                            <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR5}]]></categoryExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$V{YR5_1}]]></valueExpression>
                        </categorySeries>
                    </categoryDataset>
                    <linePlot>
                        <plot/>
                    </linePlot>
                </lineChart>
                <break>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="206" width="802" height="1"/>
                </break>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="43" y="0" width="204" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PARENT_NAME_SECTOR}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="247" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="332" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="417" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR3}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="502" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR4}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="587" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR5}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="33" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{COLUMN_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="672" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new Integer($F{YR1}.intValue() + $F{YR2}.intValue()+ $F{YR3}.intValue()+ $F{YR4}.intValue())+ $F{YR5}.intValue()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="23">
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="445" y="3" width="40" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="365" y="3" width="80" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: I have tried the . jxml files that you give. First, the row that broke out from the table. only appear one row for each page because you put startpagenew = true. When I uncheck it, the data display 5 row perpage. But the total row and chart not appear on the last page.Second, i have change group expresion is $F{PARENT_NAME_SECTOR}+ (($V{REPORT_COUNT} % 5 == 0) ? "1" : "2").I try update this file and hope you can fix it and give feedback to me

Comment: I don't know your requirements, but gave the idea how to implement that. You have to do the rest!

Comment: the situation like this. I want to display  5 row perpage in one table.The row got the number 1-5 for every page. i have try your example. yes,it is success.but the problem is data for the last page not display. i don't know why. Can you see my pictures. i have also update my code at above. you can see that code. Here my pictures.First page and last page
[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GJamQ.jpg
[2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xrfUR.jpg

Comment: The last page has no data. I mean, everything is '0'. So, maybe that's why the chart is not shown.

Comment: If you see my result pictures that i put.You can see the data for the last page has not shown because i think the problem is $V{REPORT_COUNT} % 5 == 0 in every section.Thats why, the report just read 5 data perpage. Do you think any other way how to make sure if data equal to 5 and less than 5. it will show the data. I hope you can check my code and give feedbak to me.i have try many times but the result still the same.

Comment: Should the chart appear on every page or only one chart at the last page? In the case of chart on every page, it will show data for 5 records on that respective page. So, what exactly is your requirement?

Comment: Actually i want every page contain 5 rows of data and follow by chart. so every page should have chart. My problem now if the last page contain less than 5 row of data..the total data for that row and chart will not appear. It will appear when the page contain 5 rows of data.

Comment: I just looked at the report design and the values for 'printWhenExpression' and I don't think you have tried working on the repost design that I posted here. Anyways, in the report design that I posted here, I deleted those values, but forgot to delete the value for the group footer. So, don't set any values for printWhenExpression parameter and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to create a dummy group with 'minHeightToStartNewPage' property set to something like 700/800 (depends on your report design) for 'portrait' and 500/550 (depends on your report design) for 'Landscape' setup. You can then set the value of printWhenExpression for this dummy group as '$V{REPORT_COUNT} % 5 == 0'.

NOTE: If the value of minHeightToStartNewPage is not set correctly (more than the length of page), it can run into infinite loop problems.

Comment: Dummy group?. I never saw this function in my report. how do I can get it. can you tell me?.show me for the example,please.

Comment: If you can provide me the jrxml file, I can show you how to do that.