# Issue with pagination in report: all Pages displayed on 1 screen

Tags: java, pagination, jasper-reports, reporting

I'm loading a JasperReports report (.jasper file) in an iFrame through a Servlet, and the report data is coming fine.

However, there is an issue with the way the pagination is being done. I want there to be a page-break after every 10 records, and the subsequent records should come in the next page.

The pagination code I have written in the JXRML file is:

```
<break>
    <reportElement x="0" y="23" width="802" height="15">
        <printWhenExpression>
        <![CDATA[new java.lang.Boolean((int)($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()) %10 == 0)]]>                      
        <!--![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2==0]]-->
        </printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
</break>
```

While the pagination also works with this, it shows multiple pages in the same screen - one below the other (Page 1 of 2 is shown, then below it Page 2 of 2 is shown). Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image: This is a screenshot of what it looks like.]

How can I fix this? I have tried searching on the JasperReports tutorials and community forum but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: `While the pagination also works with this, it shows multiple pages in the same screen - one below the other (Page 1 of 2 is shown, then below it Page 2 of 2 is shown)` - What do you mean? How much page do you have? Is break working or not?

Comment: Did you try this solution: [how to display data less than 5 row in jasper reports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9765774/876298)?

Comment: Hi Alex, please look at the screen-shot in the question above. You can see one row from Page 1 (brown in colour), below which it shows "Page 1 of 2". Below that, it shows the column-headers again for Page 2 and the record being shown there (with user_login_id distuser) is actually the second page. It should not be shown here below Page 1, but I expected it should have a navigation link (like "Next page" or "Page 2"), clicking on which this second page should have been displayed.

I have seen the other question that you have provided a link to - its not exactly the same kind of issue.

Comment: What is a type of generated output (html?)?

Comment: Yes, it's output-type is HTML as I'm loading it from a Servlet into an iFrame. The screen-shot you see is from the browser.