# Out of memory - Java heap space

Tags: jasperserver

I have a report which should give around 18000 pages after exporting and has 600K rows of record. It is giving me out of memory error after running. I have applied Virualization but it's not working. I also tried with increasing the memory size in tomcat server but after increasing the size the server is not starting.

Comment: Can you provide any relevant logs? Where does this out of memory error message come from?

Comment: what is the configuration of your physical machine? Probably you have memory leak or do not free memory at all. You should do job in a batch releasing memory, so that it can be reused

Comment: It's 6GB RAM and 2.3 GHz processor. And the default Tomcat settings as "-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you have not enough of RAM on your server.

Is it absolutely necessary to display report as web page? From our customers we have feedback that they never want to browse throught so many pages. It can be better to export them data directly into excel file where they have many option how to work with them.

**One solution can be to have more records on one page which leads to generate less number of pages**. But it this case with your RAM memory I am not sure that it helps

[How to control the number of rows in a JasperReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059536/how-to-control-the-number-of-rows-in-a-jasperreport)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually our design is also a bit complex. After the detail band for each Agent details, there are around 130 variables(with calculation) which are displayed in 5 group footers. The query returns around 600k rows of data.. So, what are your thoughts on this. Here we are dealing with 600k records, complex design with 130 variables with calculations..

Comment: question is who will work with this report, how and if it had to be as html page. I can not imagine that anyone will go through 600k records separated into tens or hundreds of report pages. The second thing is that probably no browser will display report with 600k records or not definitely in real time.

I suppose to give users only some small summary table/report and from this report possibility of exporting 600k recs directly into excel file.

Comment: Thanks.. We have 6 GB of RAM. And if I go by your advice what will be the possible configuration that we might need to run this report. And will it work with the default Tomcat server memory settings i.e. -Xms512m -Xmx1024m. Beacuse when I try to increase the max size(as suggested in some forums), it's throwing error syaing "JasperserverTomacat cannot start"

Comment: I am not sure how exactly jasper creates excel file. I hope it can be by direct output to the disk, but if he firstly creates whole excel in memory then you will have the same problem - not enough of memory

As a priority you should try to change memory settings of tomcat so jasper can have more of it. Is there also database on the same machine? or you have one server with 6 GB RAM only for jasper? If so then I suppose to give jasper something about 5 GB if there is nothing else which can run on that machine.